# Understanding raise in Python exception handling

Tags: python, exception

What does raise do while handling python exception?

I got some code

```
def func():
  try :
    'some code here'
  except Exception, e:
     some_issue_entry(False, ke)
     db_entry(False, ke)
     raise

  except KeyboardInterrupt, ke:
     some_issue_entry(False, ke)
     db_entry(False, ke)
     raise

  some_issue_entry(True, None)
  db_entry(True, None)
```

So here this code I was going to replace cause I don't want to write same code that is common function with different argument:

```
def func():
  success, exec = True, None
  try :
    'some code here'
  except Exception, e:
     success, exec = False, e

  except KeyboardInterrupt, ke:
     success, exec = False, ke

  some_issue_entry(success, exec)
  db_entry(success, exec)

  if not success:
     raise
```

Here are my query's:

1. how does *just* `raise` handle exception and differentiate. Because it raises the correct exception with using the first style. Does it pick from a locally stored exception?
2. while using second style is also working (not tested fully), though I have no clue why cause I am assuming raise to be associated with try, except only. Is it safe to use second style.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python stores the last caught exception with the current thread context. As such, all `raise` has to do is [retrieve that exception again](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/ceval.c#l3471):

```
do_raise(PyObject *type, PyObject *value, PyObject *tb)
{
    if (type == NULL) {
        /* Reraise */
        PyThreadState *tstate = PyThreadState_GET();
        type = tstate->exc_type == NULL ? Py_None : tstate->exc_type;
        value = tstate->exc_value;
        tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
        Py_XINCREF(type);
        Py_XINCREF(value);
        Py_XINCREF(tb);
    }
```

where `PyThreadState_GET()` looks up the current thread context.

This is documented with the [`raise` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement):

> If no expressions are present, raise re-raises the last exception that was active in the current scope.

Here *scope* is the *whole function*, not just the `except` suite.